# Override cursor property in custom textbox

Tags: c#, properties, cursor, overriding

I have problem overriding the Cursor property in my Custom Texbox. The problem is that when I add my custom textbox to a form and I change the value of the Cursur, the property will not show in the designer, it's not serialized.

```
public new Cursor Cursor
{
    get { return this.cursor; }
    set { this.cursor = value; }
}
```

I expect in designer something like:

```
... 
customTextBox1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
...
```

If I override other properties, the problem doesn't persist.

Comment: Why would you override that Property when you can use the default one?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `override` to create the property, you're using `new`, and so anytime the class is treated as either a `Control` or a `Textbox` it will use the `Control` class' version of the property, not yours, and that's...often, in this type of an environment.

If you're really sure that you want to change the way that a `Control` thinks of it's `Cursor`, you'll need to use `override`, rather than new.  If you just want to add an additional property you should consider giving the property an entirely different name, rather than shadowing an existing property.

Comment: Sorry but the property is declared virtual
`public virtual Cursor Cursor { get; set; }` (from msdn)

Comment: @kikka Odd, I wouldn't have thought.  Will update accordingly.